# how to sum multiple returns with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

My Script :

```
USE Cars

DECLARE @TotalMoneyForService money; 
DECLARE @CurrentDate date; 
DECLARE @DateCompleted date;

SET @CurrentDate =  GETDATE();

SET @DateCompleted = (SELECT DateCompleted 
    FROM ServiceType 
    WHERE DateCompleted =  @CurrentDate);

SET @TotalMoneyForService = (SELECT SUM(Price)  
    FROM ServiceType    
    WHERE DateCompleted = @CurrentDate);

PRINT @CurrentDate; 
IF  @TotalMoneyForService > 0 AND  @DateCompleted = @CurrentDate     
    PRINT 'Today Total Car Maintenance is $' +   
    CONVERT(varchar,@TotalMoneyForService,1); 
ELSE    
    PRINT 'No Car Expense Maintenance Today' ;
```

1 CASE OUTPUT:

```
2014-04-12
Today Total Car Maintenance is $43.00
```

2 CASE OUTPUT: 
I have problem here, if lets say in field DateCompleted I will have two cells with same date,lets say, 2014-04-12 I will have result:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. 2014-04-12 No Car Expense Maintenance Today

I want to get sum of Price fields if DateCompleted is = to current date so in second case it should be 53.00
I understand that I have multiple returns , and is my @DateCompleted contain two results like array? I am little bit confuse , if anyone can guide me and tell me what I am doing wrong , would really appreciate.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line of code

```
SET @DateCompleted = (SELECT top 1 DateCompleted 
    FROM ServiceType 
    WHERE DateCompleted =  @CurrentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DECLARE @TotalMoneyForService money; 
DECLARE @CurrentDate date; 
DECLARE @DateCompleted date;

SET @CurrentDate =  CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE()));

;with TotMaint
AS
(
SELECT
    SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM
    ServiceType
where
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DateCompleted)) =  @CurrentDate
)
select  
    case when Price is null THEN 'No Car Expense Maintenance Today'
    else 'Today Total Car Maintenance is $' + convert(varchar(10), Price)
    end as [Answer]
from
    TotMaint
```